# Update Query to run in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2. Common column between these tables is CustId.
Table 1 contains multiple record for one CustId whereas table2 being the master table contains just one record for Custid with all related customer information.

what i want to do is, update table2 with the most recently modified record of table1.

Since there are multiple records in the master table i want the query to run in a loop.

i have written the following,

```
update Table1 
set 
Table1.col1=b.col1,
Table1.col2 = b.col2,
Table1.col3 = case
 when b.col3 = (select Id from table4 where  name = 'Not Listed')
 then b.col4
 else b.col3
 end, 
Table1.col4 = case
 when b.col5 in (select Id from table5 where name = 'Not Listed')
 then b.col6
 else b.col5
 end
from 
    (select top 1 Table2.* 
    from Table2,Table1 where 
    Table2.CustId = Table1.CustId
    Order by 
    Table2.modifiedon desc )b

where Table1.CustId = b.CustId
```

but i am not sure if it will run for all records in table2.

Pls Help

Answer (score 0):

Please try update using inner join. Refer link [Mastering the SQL UPDATE Syntax](http://www.sqlusa.com/articles2005/updatesyntax/) for more details.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.col1=b.col1,
    T1.col2 = b.col2,
    T1.col3 = (case when b.col3 = (select Id from table4 where  name = 'Not Listed')
            then b.col4
            else b.col3 end),
    T1.col4 = (case when b.col5 = (select Id from table5 where name = 'Not Listed')
            then b.col6
            else b.col5 end)

FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustId order by modifiedon desc) Rnum,
        CustId, modifiedon, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
    FROM Table2

)x ON x.CustId=T1.CustId
WHERE x.Rnum=1
```